# using netty HttpObjectDecoder with DatagramPacket to decode SSDP message

Tags: netty

The SSDP protocol is an HTTP like protocol over UDP. I was hoping to use the netty HttpObjectDecoder / FullHttpRequest/Response classes to process it. Is there a way to put the MessagetoMessageDecoder for decoding UDP DatagramPackets into the pipeline so that the ByteBuf style TCP type decoders can use it or will I need to write a new stack that mirrors the netty Http classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by using EmbeddedChannel in your own handler. We plan to make this easier with a decorator in the future but this was not done yet[1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1350

Comment: Thanks Norman, that's where I got to this morning as well (chapter 10 made it easy - I can see me using the LogHandler and the EmbeddedChannel all the time now), i'm creating a small decoder for UDP and putting the other handlers in the embedded channel and firing the bytes in (i'm calling it a message to stream bridge). Thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm doing something obvious but can't work it out.  The EmbeddedChannel is getting the ByteBuf but it firing ChannelReadComplete instead of MessageReceived (i'm using the 5.0 API).