# Firing bytes into EmbeddedChannel

Tags: netty

I'm doing something wrong in how using EmbeddedChannel to process DatagramPacket for HttpDecoder to use as ByteBuf:

[question: using netty HttpObjectDecoder with DatagramPacket to decode SSDP message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761466/using-netty-httpobjectdecoder-with-datagrampacket-to-decode-ssdp-message)

I am using a simple MessageToMessageDecoder to fire the ByteBuf into the EmbeddedChannel:

```
    public class UdpSsdpDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<DatagramPacket>{
        private EmbeddedChannel m2sBridge;
        public UdpSsdpDecoder(EmbeddedChannel m2sBridge) {
            this.m2sBridge = m2sBridge;
        }
        @Override
        protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
            ByteBuf buf = msg.content();        
            m2sBridge.writeInbound(buf);
        }
```

The EmbeddedChannel gets the message:

```
    Sep 12, 2014 9:55:29 AM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRead
    INFO: [id: 0x5b99b997, /0.0.0.0:1900] RECEIVED: DatagramPacket(/10.1.1.12:49155 => /0.0.0.0:1900, SimpleLeakAwareByteBuf(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 133, cap: 2048))), 133B
```

...

```
    Sep 12, 2014 9:55:29 AM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRead
    INFO: [id: 0x1f759b61, embeded => embeded] RECEIVED: 133B
```

But channelReadComplete is firing rather than messageReceived (i'm using the 5.0 API):

```
    public class SsdpRequestHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Object> {
        public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object request) throws Exception {        
            System.out.println(request.toString());
        }
        public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
            ctx.flush();
        }
    }
```

*****key bits of rest of the code*****

```
    //from class with main  
    private EmbeddedChannel m2sBridge = new EmbeddedChannel();
    public void NetStart() throws Exception {        
        System.out.println("Bootstrapping the discovery server...");
        Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(group)         
        .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
         .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
         .option(ChannelOption.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 2)
         .option(ChannelOption.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP_DISABLED, true)
         .localAddress(this.port)
         .handler(createInitializer(channelGroup));        

        //set the channel.
        channel = (NioDatagramChannel) bootstrap.bind().sync().channel();
        channel.joinGroup(this.multiCastInet, NetworkInterface.getByName(this.iNet)).syncUninterruptibly();  

        //set the bridge
        m2sBridge.pipeline().addFirst(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
        m2sBridge.pipeline().addLast(new SsdpRequestHandler());        
    }

    public class DiscoveryServiceInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
        private final ChannelGroup channelGroup;
        private EmbeddedChannel m2sBridge; 

        public DiscoveryServiceInitializer(ChannelGroup channelGroup, 
                            EmbeddedChannel m2sBridge) {
            this.channelGroup = channelGroup;
            this.m2sBridge = m2sBridge;     
        }   
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
            pipeline.addFirst(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO));
            pipeline.addLast("m2sBridge", new UdpSsdpDecoder(m2sBridge));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your complete code...

Comment: Added key bits to question above.  Thanks for having a look at it.  Probably have done something obvious.

Comment: is that enough code or do you want to see all the classes?